# Fonts not supported while rendering PDF templates using PDF blocks tool

Tags: perl, pdflib

I am using Pdflib module to render the contents into PDF template and I am using it with PDF blocks plugin.
I have created PDF blocks and have added fonts to it like Arial, Calibri etc;
but while rendering it shows an error

```
Warning: Font 'Arial' with encoding 'unicode': Font file (AFM, PFM, TTF, OTF etc.) or host font not found
```

I have the fonts installed in my server and I can see it in usr/share/fonts folder, all the files have .ttf extension in the folder.
I am using the below code to render the data

```
if ($p->fill_textblock($page, $elem, $data->{$elem},"encoding=unicode") == -1) {
            printf ("Warning: %s\n", $p->get_errmsg());
        }
```

If I use the fonts in the Perl code it works fine

```
my $font = 'Arial';
 my $text_optlist ="font=".$font." encoding=unicode";
    foreach my $elem(keys %{$data}){
        if ($p->fill_textblock($page, $elem, $data->{$elem},$text_optlist) == -1) {
            printf ("Warning: %s\n", $p->get_errmsg());
        }
```

But with the blocks its not working and I am not sure what is wrong with it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Jitesh

Comment: This module: https://metacpan.org/pod/PDFLib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the fonts installed in my server and I can see it in usr/share/fonts folder, all the files have .ttf extension in the folder

you must make the fonts available for PDFlib. Please see PDFlib 9.1 Tutorial, chapter 6.4.4 "Searching for Fonts" as well chapter 3.1.4 "Resource Configuration and File Search".

In few words:
PDFlib search the font files in SearchPath director(y/ies) which you have specified with the option "SearchPath". The /usr/share/fonts is not a default directory where PDFlib search for font files.

When you want PDFlib to search in this directory, you should add this directory as a SearchPath directory

```
$p->set_option("searchpath={{/usr/share/fonts} {/maybe/some/other/dir}}");
```

Please see also the PDFlib perl samples (like starter_block.pl), which demonstrate the Searchpath as well.

Comment: I have already used that but its not working
my $searchpath = "/usr/share/fonts";
 



    my $p = new PDFlib::PDFlib;

    # This means we must check return values of load_font() etc.
    $p->set_option("errorpolicy=return");
    # Set the search path for fonts and PDF files
    $p->set_option("SearchPath={{" . $searchpath ."}}");
    
    # all strings are expected as utf8
    $p->set_option("stringformat=utf8");

Comment: might it be possible, that the font file have a upper/lower case problem? When you don't configure the font resources via the pdflib.upr file, PDFlib use the Extension based search. In your case you use the fontname **Arial**, and so it's expected the font file have also **Arial** with one of the known extension, like **.ttf**.

Comment: Yes it had that Upper case issue and now its working